# Field 'userTypeID' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to spring data, and I'm using JPA with hibernate implementation and I've create my entities.
I have users and userType tables and there is many to one mapping, but when I'm trying to persist user then a exception is thrown.

Field 'userTypeID' doesn't have a default value

Users table entity.

```html
    @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="userID")
 private long userID;

 private String firstName;

 private String lastName;

 private String emailAddress;

 private String phoneNo;

 private String address;

 private long city;

 private long state;

 private String pin;
 
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinTable(name="usertype")
 private UserType userType;
```

And my userType table entity looks like

```html
@Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="userTypeID")
 private long userTypeID;

 private String userTypeName;

 private String userTypeExtRef;
```

My service code looks like

```html
Users usr = new Users();
  
  usr.setFirstName("Akhil Chaurasia");
  usr.setEmailAddress("abc.com");
  usr.setPhoneNo("2132334343");
  UserType type = new UserType();
  type.setUserTypeID(new Long(1));
  type.setUserTypeName("abc");
  type.setUserTypeExtRef("abc");
  usr.setUserType(type);
  userDao.saveAndFlush(usr);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, its may work fine.

```html
Users usr = new Users();
  
  usr.setFirstName("Akhil Chaurasia");
  usr.setEmailAddress("abc.com");
  usr.setPhoneNo("2132334343");
  UserType type = new UserType();
 
  type.setUserTypeName("abc");
  type.setUserTypeExtRef("abc");
  usr.setUserType(type);
  userDao.saveAndFlush(usr);
```